# how to act as DHCP server using C#?

Tags: c#

I want my application(desktop app or web) to act as DHCP server to provide any pc trying to connect at my local network it's IP and DNS according to it's MAC-address .

I'm thinking to change my router's "DHCP server IP" to my PC IP ,so when another PC want to connect to network, my PC provide it by IPs?
but I don't know how to do this?
I hope my question is clear?

Comment: indeed no and I don't get why it is tagged as involving `C#`.

Comment: If you actually want to program this then you need to lookup DHCP protocol and implement it.  A couple simple good searches should get you that info or examples in C# of people trying.

Comment: to get an idea on how to do it, you could have a look at open source DHCP servers written in c#, for instance this one: https://windhcp.codeplex.com/

Comment: This is *way* too broad.  The DHCP protocol isn't super complicated, but it isn't trivial...